# scanf,fgets, fgetc get skipped inside loop

Tags: char, stdin, scanf, fgets, fgetc

Im trying to make a recursive menu.

This program will later work with a tree(hojanodo), thats why I keep track of the root.

Problem: For some reason the fgets/fgetc is being skipped inside the recursivity on the second run, why does this happen?
I want the user to input either 1,2 or 3.(int)
What would be the fix for this? and is this the best way to implement a menu?

Here's what I have right now:(It compiles and runs so you can test it out but doesn't really work like I would like to..)

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
  char ch;
  int i;
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
}hojaNodo;


int  handle_menu(int eventHandler, hojaNodo **root);
int opcion_menu();
char get_symbol();
int get_userMenuInput();
int intro();

int main(){

  hojaNodo *treeRoot = NULL;
  intro();
  // system("clear");
  handle_menu(opcion_menu(), &treeRoot);

  return 0;
}

int opcion_menu(){
  int userOption;   

  printf("1.Agrega un Simbolo.\n");
  printf("2.Listar Codigo\n");
  printf("3.Exit");

    userOption = get_userMenuInput();
    printf("User: %d",userOption);

  if(userOption < 4 && userOption > 0){
    return userOption;
  }
  else
    return -1;

}//eof opcion_menu

int handle_menu(int userOption,hojaNodo **root){
  hojaNodo *tempRoot = NULL;
  tempRoot = *root;
   int valor;
   char simbol;

  switch(userOption){
  case 1:

    simbol = get_symbol();
    printf("Simbol: %c", simbol);

    break;
  case 2:
     printf("List Nodes\n");
    break;
  case 3:
    printf("Exit");
    userOption = -1;
    // destroy_tree(root);
    break;
    default:
    printf("userOption Error, Bye!");
    break;
  }//eof switch
  if(userOption != -1)
  handle_menu(opcion_menu(),&tempRoot);
  // return userOption;
  return -1;
}//eof menu()



char get_symbol(){

    /*char userKey[3]
    fgets(userKey,len,stdin);*/
    char simbolo;
    printf("Give me a symbol.");
    simbolo = fgetc(stdin);
    return simbolo;
}

int get_userMenuInput(){

     char userKey[3];
     int userOption;
    size_t len;
     len = sizeof(userKey);
     fgets(userKey,len,stdin);
     userOption = atoi(userKey);
  //printf("User Option: %d\n", userOption);
  return userOption;
}
```

Comment: this line: 'switch(userOption){' is using userOption, however, that variable is not set to any specific value  (the variable is declared in main() but not set to any specific value, so it contains what ever trash in on the stack, at its' location in main().  It seems like the variable should be initialized to 1.

Comment: always check the returned value from fgets() and family, to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the call to fgets() will only return two bytes if all the user enters is a newlline. (and even on windows/dos system it would return 3 characters.)  suggest making the variable userkey a somewhat longer array, in the call to fgets() the second parameter should be 'sizeof userKey'' so modifications to userkey only need to be made in one place in the code.  strongly suggest the main variable eventhandler be eliminated and the call to handle_menu be changed to : handle_menu( opcion_menu(), &tempRoot );

Comment: main() is always declared to return int, so it needs a 'return value;' statement just before the final closing brace.  suggest compiling with all warnings enabled so the compiler can tell you about problems it sees in the code.  Always fix warnings.  they are there to let you know that the compiler thinks the code has some doubtful syntax/logic

Comment: the switch() code block should be in a loop that prompts for and input user input until a valid value ( 1, 2, 3, -1) is entered.  if the recursion is very deep, the message 'userOption Error, Bye!' will be output for every level of the recursion.  Note: '-1' cannot be entered by the user into a char array that is only 2 bytes long via a call to fgets().  fgets will read one byte, append a '\0' and return.  so all that will be in the array will be '-','\0'

Comment: the 'valor' variable, which is undefined, will usually contain 0 because there are a lot more keys that are not 0...9 than there are 0..9 keys

Comment: @user3629249 I've made some changes to the code, got rid of event_handler, added a return in main, made userKey bigger.
What else would you say I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Well apart from all the comments related to recursion and other changes suggested, please check this out. fgets() function needs flushing the input stream. It can be done using fflush() or fgetc().

A simple solution would be:

In function:

> int opcion_menu(){

```
...
fgets(userKey,2,stdin);
fgetc(stdin); // Add this statement
```

Also in function:

> int handle_menu(int userOption,hojaNodo **root)

```
            case 1:
                    printf("Give me a choice : ");
                    fgets(userKey,2,stdin);
                    fgetc(stdin); // add this statement
```

fgets reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by string. This will lead the newline character still available in Input Stream which need to be flushed. If this newline character is not read from Input stream, than this would become the input for next fgets function and ultimately it will skip the fgets(since it has already got its input a newline character)

fgetc(stdin) will flush out these extra newline character.

Comment: The idea is that the user inputs 1,2 or 3.
I thought It would have to be userKey= fgetc(stdin) /// also if It's a number I need, how do I change the char to int?
Thanks for your help

Comment: you can use scanf instead. scanf("%d", &choice); this will automatically convert the input to integer.

Comment: I originally started with scanf but my problem you see, is that using recursivity for the menu,makes the terminal skip the 2+ scanf's....(one of the questions..)

Comment: checkout my modifications which would justify the need for flushing of data fgetc(stdin) is to flush out the extra characters not for input of choice

Comment: Made some changes to my code, I ran it but when I go inside the menu for a second time, I getuserOption = '0'......

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this might help anyone.
In my case, I had to 'free' the buffer from the char with this function:

```
void clean(){
char cTemp;
while((cTemp = getchar()) !=  '\n')
;
}
```

Im not really sure why this works but it does(if anyone does, please add it to my answer).
I call it right before I call get_userOption();